# How to determine if an identifier needs to be delimited in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

A lot (all?) of SQL Server tools generate T-SQL quote and uniformly quote/delimit all identifiers. This is understandable, as an arbitrary identifier *may* need to be quoted. However, the generated code is less readable and a large number of identifiers *actually in use* don't need to be quoted.

I'm curious if there is a solution *in any language* that could be used to selectively quote only those identifiers that require it (to be used in T-SQL with valid syntax).

Comment: Generally speaking, it is considered to be "bad form" to name any of your data structures (tables, columns, views, SPs UDTs) using reserved words or spaces.  Therefore, (if you are following best-practices) you *should* be able to remove all delimiters.  If you get an error, it is best to reconsider your naming convention (in lieu of adding delimiters).  That was the way I was raised, at least.

Comment: @tgolisch personally I've always struggled to come up with a better name for my user table than `User`, which needs to be `[ ]`d...

Comment: "only those identifiers that require it (to be used in T-SQL with valid syntax)." - which version of T-SQL, the one now, or the one from twenty years in the future, with seven new reserved words in it?

Comment: @AakashM – I would think it would be relatively easy to change the set of reserved words that need to be quoted. I was thinking maybe a try-catch test could detect invalid 'naked' identifiers; that might work regardless of the version.

Comment: @tgolisch, reserved words change from version to version. Therefore, what were raised to believe were safe.. may not always be valid. ;)

Comment: Found a list of reserved words for sql server in case you wanted to write something yourself... http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx

Comment: [Here is an MSDN page on the rules for Transact-SQL 'regular identifiers'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874(v=sql.105).aspx) (i.e. identifiers that don't need to be delimited or quoted).

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server 2008 R2, based on [the reserved keywords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) (including the ODBC and future reserved keywords) and [the rules for regular identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), here's some example LINQPad code (for a "C# Program" query) to determine whether identifiers need to be delimited (i.e. aren't 'regular' identifiers):

```
void Main()
{
    TestIfIdentifierIsRegular("Description");
    TestIfIdentifierIsRegular("This should not be considered regular");
    TestIfIdentifierIsRegular("EntityId");
    TestIfIdentifierIsRegular("Jānis_Bērziņš");
}

void TestIfIdentifierIsRegular(string identifier)
{
    String.Format("\"{0}\" is regular? {1}", identifier, IsIdentifierRegular(identifier)).Dump();
}

bool IsIdentifierRegular(string identifier)
{
    List<string> reservedKeywords = new List<string> { "ADD", "ALL", "ALTER", "AND", "ANY", "AS", "ASC", "AUTHORIZATION", "BACKUP", "BEGIN", "BETWEEN", "BREAK", "BROWSE", "BULK", "BY", "CASCADE", "CASE", "CHECK", "CHECKPOINT", "CLOSE", "CLUSTERED", "COALESCE", "COLLATE", "COLUMN", "COMMIT", "COMPUTE", "CONSTRAINT", "CONTAINS", "CONTAINSTABLE", "CONTINUE", "CONVERT", "CREATE", "CROSS", "CURRENT", "CURRENT_DATE", "CURRENT_TIME", "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP", "CURRENT_USER", "CURSOR", "DATABASE", "DBCC", "DEALLOCATE", "DECLARE", "DEFAULT", "DELETE", "DENY", "DESC", "DISK", "DISTINCT", "DISTRIBUTED", "DOUBLE", "DROP", "DUMP", "ELSE", "END", "ERRLVL", "ESCAPE", "EXCEPT", "EXEC", "EXECUTE", "EXISTS", "EXIT", "EXTERNAL", "FETCH", "FILE", "FILLFACTOR", "FOR", "FOREIGN", "FREETEXT", "FREETEXTTABLE", "FROM", "FULL", "FUNCTION", "GOTO", "GRANT", "GROUP", "HAVING", "HOLDLOCK", "IDENTITY", "IDENTITY_INSERT", "IDENTITYCOL", "IF", "IN", "INDEX", "INNER", "INSERT", "INTERSECT", "INTO", "IS", "JOIN", "KEY", "KILL", "LEFT", "LIKE", "LINENO", "LOAD", "MERGE", "NATIONAL", "NOCHECK", "NONCLUSTERED", "NOT", "NULL", "NULLIF", "OF", "OFF", "OFFSETS", "ON", "OPEN", "OPENDATASOURCE", "OPENQUERY", "OPENROWSET", "OPENXML", "OPTION", "OR", "ORDER", "OUTER", "OVER", "PERCENT", "PIVOT", "PLAN", "PRECISION", "PRIMARY", "PRINT", "PROC", "PROCEDURE", "PUBLIC", "RAISERROR", "READ", "READTEXT", "RECONFIGURE", "REFERENCES", "REPLICATION", "RESTORE", "RESTRICT", "RETURN", "REVERT", "REVOKE", "RIGHT", "ROLLBACK", "ROWCOUNT", "ROWGUIDCOL", "RULE", "SAVE", "SCHEMA", "SECURITYAUDIT", "SELECT", "SESSION_USER", "SET", "SETUSER", "SHUTDOWN", "SOME", "STATISTICS", "SYSTEM_USER", "TABLE", "TABLESAMPLE", "TEXTSIZE", "THEN", "TO", "TOP", "TRAN", "TRANSACTION", "TRIGGER", "TRUNCATE", "TSEQUAL", "UNION", "UNIQUE", "UNPIVOT", "UPDATE", "UPDATETEXT", "USE", "USER", "VALUES", "VARYING", "VIEW", "WAITFOR", "WHEN", "WHERE", "WHILE", "WITH", "WRITETEXT", "ABSOLUTE", "ACTION", "ADA", "ADD", "ALL", "ALLOCATE", "ALTER", "AND", "ANY", "ARE", "AS", "ASC", "ASSERTION", "AT", "AUTHORIZATION", "AVG", "BEGIN", "BETWEEN", "BIT", "BIT_LENGTH", "BOTH", "BY", "CASCADE", "CASCADED", "CASE", "CAST", "CATALOG", "CHAR", "CHAR_LENGTH", "CHARACTER", "CHARACTER_LENGTH", "CHECK", "CLOSE", "COALESCE", "COLLATE", "COLLATION", "COLUMN", "COMMIT", "CONNECT", "CONNECTION", "CONSTRAINT", "CONSTRAINTS", "CONTINUE", "CONVERT", "CORRESPONDING", "COUNT", "CREATE", "CROSS", "CURRENT", "CURRENT_DATE", "CURRENT_TIME", "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP", "CURRENT_USER", "CURSOR", "DATE", "DAY", "DEALLOCATE", "DEC", "DECIMAL", "DECLARE", "DEFAULT", "DEFERRABLE", "DEFERRED", "DELETE", "DESC", "DESCRIBE", "DESCRIPTOR", "DIAGNOSTICS", "DISCONNECT", "DISTINCT", "DOMAIN", "DOUBLE", "DROP", "ELSE", "END", "END-EXEC", "ESCAPE", "EXCEPT", "EXCEPTION", "EXEC", "EXECUTE", "EXISTS", "EXTERNAL", "EXTRACT", "FALSE", "FETCH", "FIRST", "FLOAT", "FOR", "FOREIGN", "FORTRAN", "FOUND", "FROM", "FULL", "GET", "GLOBAL", "GO", "GOTO", "GRANT", "GROUP", "HAVING", "HOUR", "IDENTITY", "IMMEDIATE", "IN", "INCLUDE", "INDEX", "INDICATOR", "INITIALLY", "INNER", "INPUT", "INSENSITIVE", "INSERT", "INT", "INTEGER", "INTERSECT", "INTERVAL", "INTO", "IS", "ISOLATION", "JOIN", "KEY", "LANGUAGE", "LAST", "LEADING", "LEFT", "LEVEL", "LIKE", "LOCAL", "LOWER", "MATCH", "MAX", "MIN", "MINUTE", "MODULE", "MONTH", "NAMES", "NATIONAL", "NATURAL", "NCHAR", "NEXT", "NO", "NONE", "NOT", "NULL", "NULLIF", "NUMERIC", "OCTET_LENGTH", "OF", "ON", "ONLY", "OPEN", "OPTION", "OR", "ORDER", "OUTER", "OUTPUT", "OVERLAPS", "PAD", "PARTIAL", "PASCAL", "POSITION", "PRECISION", "PREPARE", "PRESERVE", "PRIMARY", "PRIOR", "PRIVILEGES", "PROCEDURE", "PUBLIC", "READ", "REAL", "REFERENCES", "RELATIVE", "RESTRICT", "REVOKE", "RIGHT", "ROLLBACK", "ROWS", "SCHEMA", "SCROLL", "SECOND", "SECTION", "SELECT", "SESSION", "SESSION_USER", "SET", "SIZE", "SMALLINT", "SOME", "SPACE", "SQL", "SQLCA", "SQLCODE", "SQLERROR", "SQLSTATE", "SQLWARNING", "SUBSTRING", "SUM", "SYSTEM_USER", "TABLE", "TEMPORARY", "THEN", "TIME", "TIMESTAMP", "TIMEZONE_HOUR", "TIMEZONE_MINUTE", "TO", "TRAILING", "TRANSACTION", "TRANSLATE", "TRANSLATION", "TRIM", "TRUE", "UNION", "UNIQUE", "UNKNOWN", "UPDATE", "UPPER", "USAGE", "USER", "USING", "VALUE", "VALUES", "VARCHAR", "VARYING", "VIEW", "WHEN", "WHENEVER", "WHERE", "WITH", "WORK", "WRITE", "YEAR", "ZONE", "ABSOLUTE", "ACTION", "ADMIN", "AFTER", "AGGREGATE", "ALIAS", "ALLOCATE", "ARE", "ARRAY", "ASENSITIVE", "ASSERTION", "ASYMMETRIC", "AT", "ATOMIC", "BEFORE", "BINARY", "BIT", "BLOB", "BOOLEAN", "BOTH", "BREADTH", "CALL", "CALLED", "CARDINALITY", "CASCADED", "CAST", "CATALOG", "CHAR", "CHARACTER", "CLASS", "CLOB", "COLLATION", "COLLECT", "COMPLETION", "CONDITION", "CONNECT", "CONNECTION", "CONSTRAINTS", "CONSTRUCTOR", "CORR", "CORRESPONDING", "COVAR_POP", "COVAR_SAMP", "CUBE", "CUME_DIST", "CURRENT_CATALOG", "CURRENT_DEFAULT_TRANSFORM_GROUP", "CURRENT_PATH", "CURRENT_ROLE", "CURRENT_SCHEMA", "CURRENT_TRANSFORM_GROUP_FOR_TYPE", "CYCLE", "DATA", "DATE", "DAY", "DEC", "DECIMAL", "DEFERRABLE", "DEFERRED", "DEPTH", "DEREF", "DESCRIBE", "DESCRIPTOR", "DESTROY", "DESTRUCTOR", "DETERMINISTIC", "DICTIONARY", "DIAGNOSTICS", "DISCONNECT", "DOMAIN", "DYNAMIC", "EACH", "ELEMENT", "END-EXEC", "EQUALS", "EVERY", "EXCEPTION", "FALSE", "FILTER", "FIRST", "FLOAT", "FOUND", "FREE", "FULLTEXTTABLE", "FUSION", "GENERAL", "GET", "GLOBAL", "GO", "GROUPING", "HOLD", "HOST", "HOUR", "IGNORE", "IMMEDIATE", "INDICATOR", "INITIALIZE", "INITIALLY", "INOUT", "INPUT", "INT", "INTEGER", "INTERSECTION", "INTERVAL", "ISOLATION", "ITERATE", "LANGUAGE", "LARGE", "LAST", "LATERAL", "LEADING", "LESS", "LEVEL", "LIKE_REGEX", "LIMIT", "LN", "LOCAL", "LOCALTIME", "LOCALTIMESTAMP", "LOCATOR", "MAP", "MATCH", "MEMBER", "METHOD", "MINUTE", "MOD", "MODIFIES", "MODIFY", "MODULE", "MONTH", "MULTISET", "NAMES", "NATURAL", "NCHAR", "NCLOB", "NEW", "NEXT", "NO", "NONE", "NORMALIZE", "NUMERIC", "OBJECT", "OCCURRENCES_REGEX", "OLD", "ONLY", "OPERATION", "ORDINALITY", "OUT", "OVERLAY", "OUTPUT", "PAD", "PARAMETER", "PARAMETERS", "PARTIAL", "PARTITION", "PATH", "POSTFIX", "PREFIX", "PREORDER", "PREPARE", "PERCENT_RANK", "PERCENTILE_CONT", "PERCENTILE_DISC", "POSITION_REGEX", "PRESERVE", "PRIOR", "PRIVILEGES", "RANGE", "READS", "REAL", "RECURSIVE", "REF", "REFERENCING", "REGR_AVGX", "REGR_AVGY", "REGR_COUNT", "REGR_INTERCEPT", "REGR_R2", "REGR_SLOPE", "REGR_SXX", "REGR_SXY", "REGR_SYY", "RELATIVE", "RELEASE", "RESULT", "RETURNS", "ROLE", "ROLLUP", "ROUTINE", "ROW", "ROWS", "SAVEPOINT", "SCROLL", "SCOPE", "SEARCH", "SECOND", "SECTION", "SENSITIVE", "SEQUENCE", "SESSION", "SETS", "SIMILAR", "SIZE", "SMALLINT", "SPACE", "SPECIFIC", "SPECIFICTYPE", "SQL", "SQLEXCEPTION", "SQLSTATE", "SQLWARNING", "START", "STATE", "STATEMENT", "STATIC", "STDDEV_POP", "STDDEV_SAMP", "STRUCTURE", "SUBMULTISET", "SUBSTRING_REGEX", "SYMMETRIC", "SYSTEM", "TEMPORARY", "TERMINATE", "THAN", "TIME", "TIMESTAMP", "TIMEZONE_HOUR", "TIMEZONE_MINUTE", "TRAILING", "TRANSLATE_REGEX", "TRANSLATION", "TREAT", "TRUE", "UESCAPE", "UNDER", "UNKNOWN", "UNNEST", "USAGE", "USING", "VALUE", "VAR_POP", "VAR_SAMP", "VARCHAR", "VARIABLE", "WHENEVER", "WIDTH_BUCKET", "WITHOUT", "WINDOW", "WITHIN", "WORK", "WRITE", "XMLAGG", "XMLATTRIBUTES", "XMLBINARY", "XMLCAST", "XMLCOMMENT", "XMLCONCAT", "XMLDOCUMENT", "XMLELEMENT", "XMLEXISTS", "XMLFOREST", "XMLITERATE", "XMLNAMESPACES", "XMLPARSE", "XMLPI", "XMLQUERY", "XMLSERIALIZE", "XMLTABLE", "XMLTEXT", "XMLVALIDATE", "YEAR", "ZONE" };

    if (reservedKeywords.Contains(identifier.ToUpper()))
        return false;

    Regex regularIdentifierRegex = new Regex(@"^[\p{L}_][\p{L}\p{N}@$#_]*$");

    Match match = regularIdentifierRegex.Match(identifier);

    return match.Success;
}
```

The output of running the above code as a LINQPad query:

```
"Description" is regular? True
"This should not be considered regular" is regular? False
"EntityId" is regular? True
"Jānis_Bērziņš" is regular? True
```